# Why there should not be type specifier like s or c after [0-9A-Z^%]?

Tags: c, file, scanf

For example consider the following code -

```
fscanf(fp,"%d:%d:%[^:]:%[^\n]\n",&pow->no,&pow->seen,pow->word,pow->means);     
printf("\ntthis is what i read--\n%d:%d:%s:%s:\n",pow->no,pow->seen,pow->word,pow->means);
```

here pow is pointer to an object declared before,

when I put `s` as in  `fscanf(fp,"%d:%d:%[^:]s:%[^\n]\n"` the 3rd one is read but not the last one

output is --
`4:0:Abridge::`

but when i do  `fscanf(fp,"%d:%d:%[^:]:%[^\n]s\n"`  all are read
output is --
`4:0:Abridge:To condense:`

AND without s anywhere `fscanf(fp,"%d:%d:%[^:]:%[^\n]\n"`  all are read
output is --
`4:0:Abridge:To condense:

WHY??

Comment: Not clear what you mean.

Comment: Please show what an input line looks like from your text file.

Comment: why s should fail while reading : afterwards? Can u please elaborate

Comment: @STG If `s` is present in the format string and since it's not part of the format *specifier* then `scanf()` will try to match an `s` literaly. But because it's not present in the scanned string, well it fails of course. It's the same that happens with the `':'` character, it's required in the format because it's present in the input, after very token is scanned, then `scanf()` will first try to find the text that follows and is before the next format specifier.

Comment: got it , due to s the next input till just before \n was read but not stored anywhere and when i tried again to read using [^\n] it stored nothing,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question what is the meaning of `%[^\n]s` there are two format specifier one is `[]` and another is `s`.

Now the first one will scan anything other than `\n` and then it gets a `\n` and keeps it in stdin. And move on. But it doesn't stop here - it basically then tries to find a match for the letter `s`. In case it doesn't find it - it fails. (The explanation with `%[^:]s` will be same as this one).

Now decide if this is what you really want.`[^\n]` is the right one which will scan until `\n` is found (and yes it doesn't skip whitespace like `%s` do). scanset covers the letter including `s` also.  And more than that `%[^\n]s` is self contradictory. So no use of it either.

---

```
%d:%d:%[^:]s:%[^\n]


%d - Matches an optionally signed decimal integer. (Ignore whitespace)
:  - Then looks for ':'
%d - Matches an optionally signed decimal integer. (Ignore whitespace)
:  - Then looks for ':'
%[^:] - No white space ignored - everything is taken into input except `:`
     ':' is unread.
s  - Tries to match 's'. No white space ignored.
%[^\n] - Everything except '\n' inputted. `\n` left unread.
```

Comment: See! Your answers are better than mine ... I have a *xfce4-panel* plugin to have stack overflow notifications, if you use the *xfce4* desktop I can send it to you.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi.: No way...sorry if my answering after yours sounds like that one. You and many others know it is not. I don't use it -  my laptop is pretty low ..2GB ram I dont think any other software would fit in.

Comment: can u please also tell me `[a-z,A-Z,^%]` will this read Abcd if input is Abcd%ef

Comment: what about ^  character

Comment: @STG.: Check the standard. *The characters between the brackets (the scanlist) compose the scanset, unless the character after the left bracket is a circumflex (`^`), in which case the scanset contains all characters that do not appear in the scanlist between the circumflex and the right bracket.*

Comment: @user3121023.: Actually scanset can't be used to include some characters and discard some - it is either including or excluding. Not both.

Comment: @STG.: I guess if your intention is what is mentioned in my last comment - `scanf` is not the choice for you.

Comment: @STG.: To not include `^` you would do this `scanf("%[^^]%s",s,t);` and try with input `ab^^` you will get output `ab` and `^^`.

Comment: @STG.: For including bracket add it as `[a-zA-Z-]` . It should appear nefore closing brace otherwise it won't be defined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The specifier ***IS*** `"%[]"`, you don't need the `"s"` there.

Read the [manual page for `scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Your format string doesn't match the input because you the `"s"` is not part of the specifier and it's not present in the input where the format is expecting it.

By reading the documentation in the link above, you will find out — if you don't already know — that you should also check the return value of `scanf()` before calling `printf()` or otherwise your code will invoke undefined behavior, because some of the passed pointers don't get initialized.